# Set different profiles for docker and application is JDBC Connection

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, spring-data-jpa

I want to set different profiles for docker and application is JDBC Connection.I am using the mysql configurations in Connection.java , application.properties & docker-compose file.

`Connection.java`

```
    private Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "root");
        return connection;
    }
```

`application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.port=8080
#Whether to initialize the schema on startup.
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  docker-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=databaseName
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 3307:3306

    myApp:
    image: myApp:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    depends_on:
       - docker-mysql
```

> I want to use the following profiles in **application.properties** & **docker-compose.yml**

```
1)  SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql/databaseName?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

2)  SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false

> **For JDBC Connection**
>   1) jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "root"
>   2)jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql/databaseName?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "root"

Please guide me how to set these two profiles so that my application and docker automatically adopt the profile and work perfectly

Comment: Pull application.properties outside your jar.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen sorry Sir i couldn't get your point.Could you please share the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false` in your application.properties file.

Create another file called `application-docker.properties and add spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql/databaseName?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false`

then add SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker under environment in your docker compose file

Comment: `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker` how to set this ?

Comment: i also need to automatically switch **connection String** in `createConnection()` method automatically in `docker` and simple application.